# Range of Fourier transform: criterion to belong to the range of the Fourier transform on L1

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I would like to show that a given function belongs to the range of the Fourier transform on L^1(R). 
More specifically:

given a partition of unity (g_0, g_1) on R, where g_0 has compact support around 0,I want to show that the function :

f(t) = g_1(t) /t

belongs to the range of the Fourier transform on L^1(R).

Has someone a hint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since $g_0$ is smooth and compactly supported, all of its derivatives are integrable. Therefore, for every $n$ the inverse Fourier transform $\phi = \mathcal F^{-1} g_0$  satisfies $\phi(t) =O(|t|^{-n})$ as $t\to \pm\infty$. Also, observe that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)\,dt = g_1(0)=1\tag{1}$$

Since the constant function $1$ is the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta $\delta_0$,  it follows that $g_1$ is the transform of $\delta_0-\phi$. 
Let $$h(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x (\delta_0(t)-\phi(t))\,dt = -\int_x^{\infty} (\delta_0(t)-\phi(t))\,dt $$ 
where the equality of two integral formulas follows from (1).

The decay property of $\phi$ implies that $h(x)=O(|x|^{-n})$ as $x\to \pm \infty$, for every $n$. Thus, $h \in  L^1(\mathbb R)$. By construction, the Fourier transform of $h$ is $f$, up to some constant factor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is still not clear to me why h is in L^1 though, could you explain to me how to show that please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user127674 Okay, but to make that part precise I need to know what are the assumptions on $g_0$ and $g_1$ hidden in "partition of unity". Are they Lipschitz? differentiable? etc.

Comment: Sure. The partition of unity is smooth. g_0 has compact support around 0, and is constantly equal to 1 on a smaller neighbourhood. Say g_0 = 1 on (-t,t) and g_0 = 0 outside of (-2t,2t), for some t>0. So g_1 is supported away from zero and becomes constantly equal to one outside of (-2t,2t).

Comment: @user127674 I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not convinced though. Here's what's bothering me: the integral of the dirac function is not in L1, because it equals the characteristic function of {t>0} which has infinite measure. So how can this be in L1?

Comment: @user127674 Right. And the antiderivative of $\phi$ is not in $L^1$ either. Can the sum of two non-integrable functions be integrable? Yes, it happens all the time. [Here is a plot](http://fooplot.com/plot/6eq7g4656b) of one such function: the sum of Heaviside step with something else.